# Problema con la condición if

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo un objeto con una serie de true o false,

```
let pbi=
{
  task1:true,
  task2:false, 
  task3:true,
}
```

en caso de que todas las task sean true me gustaría escribir un alert.

Comment: Ya sabes lo que tienes, y ya sabes lo que quieres... sin embargo afirmas tener un problema con un condicional `if`... dónde está dicho condicional? Porque tal cual está tu pregunta parece que tu problema se redefine a *falta de investigación e intentos de resolverlo(esfuerzo, vaya)*. Y me temo que ese tipo de problemas no son bienvenidos en StackOverflow, aquí solo podemos ayudarte con problemas concretos con el código, no damos clases particulares, hacemos tutoriales ni trabajamos para nadie. Si tienes un problema concreto estamos encantados de ayudarte, si no lo intentas primero... imposible

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Puedes usar [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) para obtener los valores de un objeto como array, y luego usar [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) para recorrerlo y obtener el resultado final en el acumulador.

```js
let pbi={
   task1:true,
   task2:false,
   task3:true
}

let res = Object.values(pbi).reduce((a,i) => a = a && i,true);

console.log(res);
```

---

**Explicación:**

Para determinar si todos los valores son verdaderos se puede ocupar un `if`

```
if(pbi.task1 == true && pbi.task2 == true && pbi.task3 == true ){
  console.log("TODAS LAS TAREAS SON TRUE");
}
```

O que es lo mismo que:

```
let variable = pbi.task1 == true && pbi.task2 == true && pbi.task3 == true;
if(variable){
  console.log("TODAS LAS TAREAS SON TRUE");
}
```

Luego como task es un booleando true/false se puede resumir la condición de esta manera:

```
let variable = pbi.task1 && pbi.task2 && pbi.task3;
```

Ahora lo que entiendo es el problema de fondo, es que task1 es una lista de tareas, donde podrían haber de 1 a n, donde el código anterior solo funciona para 3 tareas.

```
let variable = pbi.task1 && ..... && pbi.task_n;
```

Luego hay que tener en cuenta que si yo agrego un `true` a la secuencia no cambio nada, es como sumar cero

```
let variable = true && pbi.task1 && ..... && pbi.task_n;
```

Si ocupo [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) sobre el objeto obtengo una lista de valores booleanos, lo que me permite recorrerlo con un `for` y generar la secuencia antes mencionada

```
let a = true; //valor inicial
for(let i of Object.values(pbi)){
  a = a && i;
}
```

Ahora esto se puede resumir usando un [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), siendo el equivalente de este for:

```
Object.values(pbi).reduce((a,i) => a = a && i,true);
```

(El true que aparece es el valor inicial)

---

Como nota aclaratoria, esto funciona para cualquier secuencia de tareas desde 1 a n. Si se requiere de cero a n, habría que agregar un condicional anterior:

```js
let pbi={
   task1:true,
   task2:false,
   task3:true
}

let valores= Object.values(pbi);
let res =  valores.length>0 && valores.reduce((a,i) => a = a && i,true);

console.log(res);
```

---

**Update**

Con la función [evey](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) resulta más fácil

```js
let pbi={
   task1:true,
   task2:false,
   task3:true
}

let valores = Object.values(pbi);
let res = valores.length>0 && valores.every(task=>task);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Le hiciste la tarea. Nice...

Comment: Recuerda Yussef, no se viene acá a hacer la tarea a los demás. Tiene todo lo necesario para realizar la tarea, y no hizo nada más que pegar el enunciado en SOes...

Comment: @Excorpion A mí no me queda claro si es una tarea, por el contrario me parece una duda puntual y acotada. Y mi opinión al respecto queda 100% reflejada en esta publicación https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4125/301324 que hizo un usuario hace años.

Comment: Entonces debes analizar un par de cosas antes, si tienes duda si es tarea o no, consúltate, ¿Ha hecho algún progreso?(Acá, no hay) ¿su pregunta es solo enunciado?(si, solo enunciado) ¿Es de carácter "tengo esto" y "necesito hacer esto"?(Esta, si). Estas simples dudas son un buen criterio para estas cosas, y toparte con estos momentos que pueden ser de mal gusto.. Con respecto a tu respuesta, creo que lo tienes claro, y si no te importa que otros sigamos corrigiendo el tema de "No hagas la tareas de quien no se esfuerza", no veo que debas tomar comentario alguno (y)

Comment: btw, es mas simple identificar estas malas preguntas/sin esfuerzo, dado que son cerradas rapidamente... eso es un nono a responder.

Comment: Yo no me voy  a centrar en si respondiste un ejercicio o no. Lo que si te voy a aclarar, es que no estoy seguro que esto resuelva el problema, porque como le falta una explicacion, entonces no se entiende como resuelve el problema. que hace a && i por ejemplo?

Comment: @gbianchi Ahí agregue la explicación, francamente no entiendo porque la pediste si probablemente esta publicación será borrada.

Comment: yo no la pedi.. pero es como que tu respuesta, mas alla de que OP no hizo absolutamente nada, era solamente codigo... no explicaba porque solucionaba el problema...